# compare sting and data attribute add class if it matches

Tags: jquery

With Jquery how would I add a class to an element only when the string matches the name of a custom data attribute.

For instance:

```
<ul>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item1</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-2</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-3</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-4</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add class only on item-3 based on the fact that the data attribute matches the string inside the element. Alternatively, I could also give the elements a class name, value or differnt data attribute that has the same name as the string and compare that to the data-attr instead, if it simplifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("data-attr") === $(this).text()) {
    $(this).addClass("new");
  }
});
```

```css
.new {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item1</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-2</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-3</li>
  <li data-attr="item-3">item-4</li>
</ul>
```

Update: As mentioned as comment, the code can have more than one entry for `data-attr`. This can be handled as follows:

```js
$("li").each(function() {
   let attr = $(this).attr("data-attr");
   let values = attr.split(" ");
   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i] === $(this).text()) {
         $(this).addClass("new");
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.new {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-attr="item-1 item-3">item-1</li>
  <li data-attr="item-1 item-3">item-2</li>
  <li data-attr="item-1 item-3">item-3</li>
  <li data-attr="item-1 green">green</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works perfectly but I'm now realising that in reality the code might have more then one item in data-attr, so it could be data-attr="item-1 item-3" and I would need to have both of the associated li elements to get the class .new added.

Comment: apologies, item-1 item-2 etc was to try and make a simple example, the actual terms could be anything, red, blue, small, medium etc etc. I could prefix each with a term like item if it helps, but it looks like you use the numerical values which I wouldn't have.

Comment: @fred No, that was a misunderstanding. The previous solution just used "items" as a variable name and checked if the text is contained in the data-attributes. I've updated my answer with a better approach to check for an exact match instead (the previous answer would have added the class e.g. if the text would be "gree" and one of the data-attributes would be "green" as "green" contains "gree", which won't happen now).